# Не передаются параметры tomcat

Tags: java, tomcat

Поскольку не хочется хранить пароль от БД в коде, он хранится в системных параметрах, но на Tomcat есть проблема. В папке с томкатом [именно дистрибутив,](https://tomcat.apache.org/download-90.cgi)

в директории /bin лежит файл setenv.bat
Tomcat запускаю через Eclipse, не через startup.bat. Один раз удалось передать переменную через setenv.bat, но когда я сменил пароль от БД, сменил его также в setenv.bat(переустановил tomcat и setenv), переменная остаётся одной и той же. Также создал /bin/setenv.bat в CATALINA_BASE, которая находится в F:\Eclipse\eclipse-ee-workspace.metadata.plugins\org.eclipse.wst.server.core\, не помогло.

Comment: вы все в кучу смешали, через экслипс на вашей винде, на хостинге, в какой репозиторий вам не хочется выкладывать пароль, ничего не понятно

Comment: @StrangerintheQ имеется ввиду если на Github выкладывать в репозиторий, то пароль будет виден для всех.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Я нашёл решение. Случайно читал про переменные и среды и там использовался метод

```
System.getenv().get("name");
```

До этого я использовал

```
System.getenv("name");
```

Не знаю, чем отличаются эти методы, но при использовании setenv.bat/sh в tomcat корректно будет работать первый метод.